# Java += operator

Tags: java, operator-keyword

as far as I understand x+=1  works as x=x+1, but why it doesn't work in String?

```
String str = "";
str = str + null + true; // fine
str += null + true; // Error message: The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) null, boolean
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, [expression are evaluated from left to right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7). Thus

```
str = str + null + true;
```

is the same as

```
str = (str + null) + true;
```

and `null` and `true` are implicitly converted to `String`s. This works because in `str + null`, the compiler knows that `str` is a `String` and converts `null` to a `String`. This is possible because every value can be converted to a `String` in Java. By the same line of argumentation, the compiler knows that `(str + null)` is a `String` and thus coverts `true` to a `String`.

On the other hand,

```
str += null + boolean;
```

is equivalent to

```
str = str + (null + boolean);
```

hence, `null + boolean` is evaluated first. Since the operator `+` is not defined for types `null, boolean`, a compiler-error is generated.